# Zeroconf library for windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, mono, zeroconf

I'm making a Windows 8 metro app that needs to use a `zeroconf library`. From what I've observed, there are a few of those libraries and the most trustworthy looking one is `Mono.Zeroconf`. However I can't seem to install it via NuGet, I get an error saying that "Mono.Zeroconf could not be installed because it is not compatible with any project in the solution."

> "The package targets the following frameworks: .NETFramework,
>   Version=v2.0"

.

Are there any well documented alternatives to Mono.Zeroconf or anything I can do to make it work on my Windows 8 app?

Edit: Ok, I'm trying to use the zeroconf library [here](https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf), but I'm getting an error just by calling the simplest function. When I call

```
await ZeroconfResolver.BrowseDomainAsync();
```

I get an error with the message:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Socket is already bound to an address.
>
> Additional information: A method was called at an unexpected time.

Anyone have any idea why this might happen or how it can be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this [https://github.com/onovotny/Zeroconf ] & [http://www.nuget.org/packages/Zeroconf ]

Comment: I hadn't seen onovotny's repository, thanks.

Comment: Hi ! So how did you manage to have it work ? I get the same exception.

Comment: I didn't. I couldn't find a way out and I just gave up.

Comment: OK, so i found a way... I disconnected my second unused network card in the control panel, and the problem gone...